# check if the if statement remains true

Tags: javascript

first let me say that this is my first post so bear with me if I write my question poorly or something ...

But I have this code where I check if a div has a particular class, if it has, it must pick up some items that are styled in a certain way, otherwise get another styling.

My problem is that the if statement only gets checked once, so when I for example start with a window which completely fills the entire screen, and then resize it down to mobile size, it wont check my IF statement agian, and there for do not run it, and it retains the styling from Else statement wich i dont like.

so my question is, is there an opportunity to check on the IF statement is still true when resizing and without using too much bandwith, and checking it constantly ??

```
$.getJSON("GetContent?id=@Model.Id", function (data) {
            var config;
            if ($('html').hasClass('js-mobile')) {
                $('.banner').remove();
                config = HCP.templateConfigurations.mobileConfig();
            } else {
                config = HCP.templateConfigurations.defaultConfig();
            }
            config.data = data;
            createSlider(config);
        });
```

Comment: In a nutshell: you'll need to listen to specific events the browser emits (e.g. upon resizing) and run whatever you need to run again. – The long answer may be that you should avoid this kind of thing altogether and maybe go with a unified responsive solution which changes things purely by CSS or such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it in a function and call when resizing is finished:

```
    window.onresize = function(){
      clearTimeout(nowDoIt);
      nowDoIt = setTimeout(myFunctionHere, 100);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably make it a window resize callback:

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
        if ($('html').hasClass('js-mobile')) {
            $('.banner').remove();
            config = HCP.templateConfigurations.mobileConfig();
        } else {
            config = HCP.templateConfigurations.defaultConfig();
        }
 })
```

So the full code could look like:

```
$.getJSON("GetContent?id=@Model.Id", function (data) {
    var config = check();
    config.data = data;
    createSlider(config);
});

$(window).scroll(check);

function check(){
    if ($('html').hasClass('js-mobile')) {
        $('.banner').remove();
        return HCP.templateConfigurations.mobileConfig();
    } else {
        return HCP.templateConfigurations.defaultConfig();
    }
}
```

Comment: On scroll? Not on resize?

Comment: This would fail on device orientation change, which is effectively a resize

Comment: @nnnnnn ahhhh, sorry, was writing a scroll question just before this :) Thanks, fixed it.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Sorry, was thinking about resize the whole time, but wrote scroll... :/